# Horizontal Scroll React component

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I need React component that will do exact thing like this: [HorizontalScroll](https://gfycat.com/betteraggravatingindianglassfish).

Here is the component that is used in this case [scroll-horizontal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-horizontal).

Answer (score 0):

Probably they are using a combination of CSS properties like `overflow-x: scroll; scrollbar-width: none;`

That component you linked will work fine in react, but is easier to implement if the component has been design with React in mind. Like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-horizontal

Answer (score 0):

try: https://react-hv.vercel.app/

npm:

```
npm install --save react-horizontal-vertical
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you wrote the library, you should disclose that. Your recent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74412379/18244921) suggests that you are the author.